# Python Werkzeug: modify Request values (forms and args) prior to retrieval

Tags: python, werkzeug

Is there a way in Werkzeug to edit the request values (forms and args) before using it?

I need to encode the request values from utf8 to iso88591. I created a function to handle this.

I would like to use this function on all form values so that I avoid the second line of the following:

```
lcl_var = request.form['post_arg']        
lcl_var = encode_utf8_to_iso88591(lcl_var)
```

I couldn't figure out what I needed from the Werkzeug [docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/). I imagine there's a way to subclass the Request class and override a one of its methods that handles the values. Would really appreciate a concrete example on how to implement this well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A limited example exists on extending request parsing at the Werkzeug docs.  It's a little buried, but it's sound.

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/request_data/#how-to-extend-parsing

Since Werkzeug is a pretty low-level tool over HTTP, this functionality could also be implemented in your request dispatcher (assuming a structure similar to the one in the Werkzeug tutorial, the function that applies the url map to the request.)

**EDIT**:

It seems that per the Werkzeug docs, the best way to do this is to process your own request property out of the stream.  It'd be nice to do this is a way that preserves the immutability of the `request.form` property:

```
def encode(value):
    #Your logic for the new dict vals
    return 'foo!'

class MixInRequest(Request):
    max_content_length = 1024 * 1024 * 4

    @cached_property
    def lcl_data(self):
        if self.method in ['POST','PUT','PATCH']:
            fields = dict([(key, encode(val)) for (key,val) in self.form.items()])
            return ImmutableMultiDict(fields)
        return None
```

This sets a request property `lcl_data` (named after your function) that will parse on first access and cache for subsequent calls.  It only functions for methods that would populate `request.form`.

Full example here:

https://gist.github.com/DeaconDesperado/7292574

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would I basically have to do something like this in the dispatcher: `request.form = parse_form_data(environ)[1]`. If so, how would I override parse_form_data?

Comment: It would probably be best to preserve the immutability of the request dict, so the best approach is probably the one outlined here: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/?highlight=request.form#base-wrappers  This allows you to mixin your custom request object, and override `form_data_parser`.  Will edit answer.

Comment: Reading the docs, it looks like setting a custom property with its own dictionary representation right off the stream might be best.  Here's a working example I came up with using the docs, sorry for the confusion:
https://gist.github.com/DeaconDesperado/7292574

Comment: Will edit with link once confirmed working.  I'm pretty sure this should be good, but you may want to let decode errors bubble up for catch in the app depending on your use case.

Comment: Last question: to access the encoded values, do I have to use something like: `lcl_var = request.lcl_data['post_arg']` instead of `request.form['post_arg']`? Edit: Yup, got it to work. Grateful for your help!

Comment: Can you put your example in your answer? I think would be very useful for future visitors of this page.

Comment: All set.  Example and explanation of the immutabledict and caching decorator included.