# Put text into input html field using Flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I know I can easily extract data from html input tag using `request.form['email']` after POST method.
Is there a way to populate this particular input tag with something like:

```py
request.form['email'] = current_user.email
```

which obviously throws `'ImmutableMultiDict' objects are immutable`? (Without using FlaskWTF).
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a default value for "input type=text" without using attribute 'value'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610540/how-to-define-a-default-value-for-input-type-text-without-using-attribute-val)

Comment: @LukasSchmid no, I need to make this using Flask (of course if it's possible). Maybe, it can be done with jinja somehow, idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this could be easily done using `value` attribute, e.g.:

```html
<input class="email" name="email" value="{{ current_user.email }}" required/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite request.form :

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict
from flask import Flask,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # overwrite request.form to add 'email'
    tempo_form_dict = request.form.to_dict()
    tempo_form_dict['email'] = 'Hello@World'
    request.form = ImmutableMultiDict(tempo_form_dict)
    
    ## Then you can use request.form as it was inputted...
    
    return str(request.form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host=None,port=5000)
```

a linked question: [Python Werkzeug: modify Request values (forms and args) prior to retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755158/python-werkzeug-modify-request-values-forms-and-args-prior-to-retrieval)